# Why does AWS amplify does not recognize updated node version?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I upgraded node on my local machine as well as migrated from `create-react-app` to `nextjs`.

When I pushed my code to AWS Amplify, I got this error:

```
error game-night@0.1.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12.22.0". Got "12.21.0"

error Found incompatible module.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

I've looked on stackoveflow and other blogs and I've tried everything, but I still get this error.

My trials:

- Added engines: node to my package.json

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=12.22.0"
  }
```

- Ran these commands:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
```

- Double checked my node version:

```
node -v                                                                              
v16.13.0
```

- Deleted and then installed the node modules folder with yarn install

Why is this error still occurring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are only using node v16 locally, amplify for some reason uses a lower one. You could either downgrade the package (not recommended imho) or tell amplify to use a higher node version (recommended imho).

```
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - nvm install 16
```

Find the official documentation on how to change build settings here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html

Answer (score 5):

Another way to solve this is [editing the Amplify build settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioJgH.png)
You can specify that Amplify use a specific Node.js version under App Settings -> Build Settings -> Add Package Version Override.

Comment: This is the correct answer. From the Amplify docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/custom-build-image.html 

"Our build runner does not install Node, but instead relies on Node and NPM being installed in the image. This is only required for builds that require NPM packages or Node specific commands."

Comment: Yes this answer helped me